# Create new proper time-dataset from raw data with Python

Tags: python, excel, spyder, xlsx, data-transform

First of all, I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but I believe my challenge is specific enough. I'm not looking for complete answers but simply guidelines on how I can proceed.

1. First of all, I have a raw dataset of monitoring participants. This data include things like income, savings, etc... and these participants have been tracked for 6 months (Jan to Jun). But the data is stored in a whole single Excel file with a column to specify the month, which means that one participant's name comes back 6 times in the file, one for each month. Each participant has a unique ID.
2. I want to transfrom this data in a more workable way and I wanted to learn to do it with Python. But then I feel stuck and rusty because it's been ages since I've coded and I'm only used to the codes I use on a regular basis (printing grouped averages, etc...); Here's the steps I want to follow:

a. Start by creating a column which contains a unique list of participants that have been tracked using the ID. Each participant has to be cited once only;

b. Each participants is recorded with an activity and sub-activity type in the original file, which will need to be added in the new dataset as well;

c. For the month of January for example, I want to create a 'january_income' column in which the income from january has been dragged from the raw dataset, and so on for each variable and each month.

Can anyone provide guidelines on how I may proceed? As I said, it doesn't have to be specific codes, it can be methods or steps along with the function I can use.

Thanks alot already.
N.B: I use Spyder as a working environment.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! For now, im flagging this question as "needs more focus" because it seems like this question is asking multiple steps at once. Please note that Stackoverflow is not a free tutorial provider , this question asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Here are some suggestions : You can edit the question to focus on a specific step/part of your question and provide your code attempts on it. Stack overflow is more of a problematic code helper rather than a free code/tutorial provider. Anyways goodluck :D

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific. But you can try and adjust the code below:

```
import csv
"""
Convert your excel file to csv format
This sample assumes that you have a csv file with the first row as header or fieldnames
"""
with open('test.csv','w') as fp:
    fp.write("""ID,Name,Income,Savings,Month
1,"Sample Name",1000,100,1
""")
def format(infile = 'infile.csv', outfile='outfile.csv'):
    months = ['January', 'February', 'March'] #Add specific months
    target_fields = ['Income', 'Savings'] # Add your desired fields
    timestamp_field = 'Month'  #The field which indicate the month of the row
    ID_field = 'ID' # The field which indicates the unique identifier of the participant
    part_specific_fields = [ID_field, 'Name'] # The fields which are specific for each participant, these fields won't be touched at all.
    target_combined_fields = [f'{month}_{field}' for field in target_fields for month in months]
    total_fields = part_specific_fields + target_combined_fields
    temp = {}
    with open(infile,'r') as fpi, open(outfile,'w') as fpo:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fpi)
        for row in reader:
            ID = int(row[ID_field])
            if ID not in temp:
                temp[ID] = {}
            for other_field in part_specific_fields:
                # Insert the constant columns that should not be touched
                temp[ID][other_field] = row[other_field]
            month_pos = int(row[timestamp_field]) - 1 # subtract 1 for 0 indexing
            month = months[month_pos] # Month name in plain English
            for field in target_fields:
                temp[ID][f'{month}_{field}'] = row[field]
         # All the processing completed
         #now write the data
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fpo, fieldnames=total_fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in temp.values():
            writer.writerow(row)
        # File has been wriiten successfully
        #now return the mapped dictionary
    return temp
print(format('test.csv'))
```

1. First, You have to convert your `.xls` file to `.csv` format
2. Process the each row and map that to specific `<month>_<field>` keys.
3. Write the processed data to `outfile.csv` file

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the notes. First of all, I'm sorry if my post is not specific and thanks for initiating me on the community. Since my initial post, I've made some effort to work on my data and with my actual knowledge of the langage, all I could come up with was a filtering code as my code below shows. This lets me have a column for each data of each month okay but I'm stuck on two things: first, I had to repeat this code for each month and change the months in the labels. I wouldn't have minded that approach if I didnt have to face another problem: This doesn't take in account the fact that some participants have not been tracked on certain months, which means that even if the data was sorted according to ID number, there is a mismatch between the columns because their length vary according to the number of participants tracked for that month. Now I'm looking to optimize this code by adding a line which would let me resolve my second issue (at this point I don't mind if the code is long but if there could be optimization to be made at all, I'm open to it as well):

```
os.chdir("XXXXXXX")
economique = pd.read_csv('data_economique.csv')
#JANVIER
ID_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["ID"]
nom_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["nom"]
sexe_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["sexe"]
district_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["district"]
activite_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["activite"]
CA_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["chiffre_affaire"]
charges_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["charges"]
resultat_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["benefice"]
remb_attendu_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["remb_attendu"]
remb_effectue_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["remb_effectue"]
remb_differe_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["calcul_remb_differe"]
epargne_jan = economique.query("mois_de_suivi == 'Janvier'")["calcul_epargne"]
```